# LastInserID from other table insert to table

Tags: pdo, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

how i can select lastinserid from table player and insert into to test_table?

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO baza.test_table (`player`) VALUES (?)");

   $a = mt_rand(1, 100);
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $a, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
   print $pdo->lastInsertId().'<br/>';
   $pdo = null;
```

when i create account id is (autoincromentet) i want insert this id to another table

Comment: What is your problem? Why you're printing lastInsertId() instead of assigning it to a variable and using in another query?

Comment: @YourCommonSense do you mean $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT FROM baza.player (`id`)");

Comment: I mean you are ALREADY using the proper function - $pdo->lastInsertId(). Why don't you assign its result to a variable, `$id=$pdo->lastInsertId();` and than use this variable in another query?

Comment: @YourCommonSense i arleady try it but dont work i get id from insert i want id from other table

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: @YourCommonSense create account = autoincromented id table=account   i want insert this id to table=test